Chrome Extension Почему пишет что метот не найден хотя код взят с документации
const css = "body { background-color: red; }";

chrome.scripting
    .insertCSS({
      target : {tabId : 108522522},
      css : css,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("CSS injected"));

Код взят с документации https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/scripting?hl=ru
Но почему то выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertCSS')
Мои manifest
    "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
],
"permissions": [
    "scripting",
    "storage",
    "cookies",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
],


Вам надо проверять всю цепочку chrome.scripting Что то из этого undefined

в каком файле расположен этот код?

Расположен в content.js

@Lotti судя по наличию поля "tabId", этот метод не доступен из контента.
